# How to set first URL as base url dynamically in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am injecting my angular2 application in another app division and by default the url is contains a big query string. How I will set that url and query string as my base url in angular2

```
exp url: http.example.com/this/thai?this=thhtyy&ttthh


{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are using / as your base URL. you can change your base URL to your first url you are getting in you code.

```
{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window.document.location.href}
```

Comment: it resolved my issue but its trying to find my static content and javascript files in that url. I want my static contents should be as it is. any idea?